# Is there any way to pass custom state or context from the client through identityserver3 to a custom IdP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I am working on a spike with the following architecture:

[asp.net mvc client] --> [identity server 3 with custom middleware] --> [custom IdP]

The spike is to prove out that a more open, standards-based approach is better than yet another bespoke solution that serves only one purpose.

The functionality flow I require is such that:

1. the client will perform a user search and retrieve a customer id
2. the user will then requested a restricted resource providing that customer id
3. the OpenId connect pipeline then redirects them through to the custom IdP
4. the custom IdP presents a page of secret questions for that user which must be answered in order for them to be authenticated
5. authentication occurs and passes the user back through idsvr3 to the client upon which they can access the restricted resource.

My question is - is this achievable? The state is encrypted on the client and should effectively be considered unencryptable. I have access to the source code for the client, the idsvr3 instance, the custom middleware and the custom IdP, so any magic tricks anyone can think of should be achievable.

I'm using the latest NuGet package for OpenIdConnect in the MVC client.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the resource identifier – or the desired end location – in the request or a cookie, and when you hit your `wreply` page, check for it and send a `302`.  This is entirely within the spec, and only requires modifications to the RP.

#### OpenID Connect

[The `state` parameter](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.3.1.2.1):

> RECOMMENDED. Opaque value used to maintain state between the request and the callback. Typically, Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF, XSRF) mitigation is done by cryptographically binding the value of this parameter with a browser cookie.

#### WS-Federation

This is the [purpose of the `wctx` parameter](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/dw/specs/ws-fed/WS-Federation-V1-1B.pdf?S_TACT=105AGX04&S_CMP=LP):

> This optional parameter is an opaque context value that MUST be returned with the issued token if it is passed in the request. Note that this serves roughly the same purpose as the WS-Trust SOAP RST @Context attribute. In order not to exceed URI length limitations, the value of this parameter should be as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by:

1. intercepting the response within the Global.asax.cs Application_EndRequest and appending the identifier
2. Reading this identifier in the request to the authorize endpoint in idsvr3
3. Padding this parameter through all the calls until my custom auth middleware was called
4. Appending this parameter onto my redirect url